# Finding point(s) on ellipse closest to origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The question is asking for the point(s)that are the closest to the origin on the ellipse 
$5x^2-6xy+5y^2=8$

I used the distance formula $d^2=x^2+y^2$

And found the x and y components to be
$2x=(10x-6y) \lambda$ and $2y=(10y-6x) \lambda$.

$\frac{2x}{2y} =\frac{(10x-6y)\lambda}{(10y-6x)\lambda}$

$10xy-6x^2 =10xy-6y^2$
$-6x^2=-6y^2$
$x^2=y^2$
$x=y$

$5x^2 -6x^2+5x^2 =8$ => $4x^2 =8$ => $x=\pm2$ ; $y=\pm2$

When I solved for x and y I got both of them to be 
$x=\pm 2$
 and $y=\pm2$
I am not sure if this is correct not but when I graphed the ellipse my points appear to be outside of the ellipse. 
Please let me know if this is the correct method to solve this and if I am doing it correctly. Thank You
 [Image of ellipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vNtA.png)

Comment: Well, since the points don’t lie on the ellipse, then you’ve certainly not done it correctly, but unless you show your work, it’s going to be very hard to tell you just where you went wrong. Incidentally, you didn’t need to graph the ellipse to find out that your answer was incorrect: check your own work by plugging the coordinates of the points into the equation of the ellipse.

Comment: Also, by $x=\pm2$ and $y=\pm2$, do you mean to say that you found four or two solutions? If the latter, then which combination of signs do you mean by this?

Comment: I am not sure on how to proceed after finding x and y. I have gone over my work but I am not able to spot anything so I think I may have been doing it wrong the entire time.

Comment: you did everything right up until solving $4x^2=8$

Comment: If I am to do this with the Lagrange how will I proceed at that step?

Comment: @WW1 Actually, the first mistake was going from $x^2=y^2$ to only $x=y$. There’s a second possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the derivative of

$$5x^2-6xy+5y^2=8$$

$$y’=\frac{3y-5x}{5y-3x}$$

If the point on the curve is the closest to the origin, the following relationship can be established,

$$ -\frac xy =\frac{3y-5x}{5y-3x}$$

which leads to

$$x=\pm y$$

Plug $x=-y$ back into the original equation to get

$$x^2=\frac 12$$

Thus, the closest points are $(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2})$ and $(-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},\frac{1}{\sqrt 2})$.

Note that the line connecting these two points is the minor axis. The other solution $x=y$ leads to the two points along the major axis, which are not the closest. You were focusing on $x=y$ instead of $x=-y$.

Comment: Oh I see. I guess I overlooked that part. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You were doing well until you went from $x^2=y^2$ to $x=y$: another possibility is $x=-y$. The second mistake came at $4x^2=8$: the solutions are $\pm\sqrt2$, not $\pm2$, which is why the points weren’t on the ellipse. This gives you one pair of points, $\pm(\sqrt2,\sqrt2)$, at a distance of $2$ from the origin.

Now you have to try the other possible solution to $x^2=y^2$. Setting $y=-x$, we eventually get the equation $16x^2=8$, which yields the points $\pm(1/\sqrt2,-1/\sqrt2)$, at a distance of $1/2$ from the origin, so these are the solutions to your exercise.